# partial derivatives question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> If $u$ = $f(x,y)$, where $x = e^s\cos t$ and $y = e^s\sin t$, show
>   that 
>   $$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2} = e^{-2s}\left[\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial s^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}\right]
> $$

I'm not sure where to start. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Example)?

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial y}
$$

or the inverse

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}
$$

You can use the second pair of rules, then solve for the desired quantities, or use the first pair of rules after obtaining $s(x,y), t(x,y)$ from the definitions of $x,y$.

Then you should proceed in a similar way for the second derivatives.

#### Edit

Going into the calculations:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}&=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}=\\
    &=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}e^s\cos t+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}e^s\sin t=\\
    &=x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}&=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=\\
    &=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}e^s\sin t+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}e^s\cos t=\\
    &=-y\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
\end{align}

This is true for every function $u$, so

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial s}&=x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}&=-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}
\end{align}

so we have

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial s^2}&=\left(x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\left(x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)\\
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}&=\left(-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\left(-y\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)
\end{align}

I suppose that from here you can go on without help.

Comment: mmm.. i don't fully understand how to use the chain rule formula. And i have trouble coming up with an equation for $f(x,y)$. Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: @uohzxela: I edited the answer.